# Negative values in byte[] in Java, but not in Python

Tags: java, python, arrays, byte

Why does Java allow byte arrays to contain negative values such as

```
byte[] array = new byte[-90, -23, 118, 23, 3, 0, 0, 23, 39]
```

but Python does not?

Comment: JAva bytes are always signed.

Comment: @akuzminykh Ah, makes sense! But how can Java byte[] contain these values?

Comment: @akuzminykh I understand, but why doesn't Python let me do this then: array = bytearrau([-90, -23, 118, 23, etc...]) ?

Comment: It's simply a different way of using 8 bits. In Java a `byte` is signed and ranges from -128 to 127. But you can also use 8 bits to represent a range from 0 to 255. That's useful e.g. when you work with encodings or when you want to represent color. This Python function is probably meant for that.

Comment: python array module accepts signed int `array.array('b', [-90, -23, 118, 23, 3, 0, 0, 23, 39])`, its work

Comment: @WillianVieira Thank you!

Comment: It depends on how you view the 8 bits in a byte.  Java has chosen a completely brain dead and useless view (probably to be consistent with int and long which _are_ useful),   which frequently confuses beginners.